# why is `less` command using too `much` ram

Tags: less

I was using less to examine a rather large file (8GB on a machine with 4GB RAM).  I told it to "scroll to the end" (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and it ran for quite awhile then was killed for using up RAM.  I thought `less` wouldn't use more than a limited amount of RAM am I missing something?

Comment: Have you got an adequate swap partition (or file)? Are you using a 32-bit OS?

Comment: Basically no swap.  But shouldn't less...you know...not need to read the whole file into memory, that's my question mark here... :)

Comment: I think it probably does read the whole file into memory, which is obviously impossible with your system. Try creating and enabling a swap file as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq), but don't bother if you have a 32-bit OS.

Comment: See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)#Memory_considerations) for information on `less`'s memory requirements.

Comment: Interestingly, if I use `-B` it doesn't use "unlimited RAM" but if I specify `--buffers=64` it uses up all memory in the system (despite the fact it's reading from a file, not a pipe).  Anyway `-B` fixes it, feel free to create an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: FWIW in this case it was reading from a file that is "currently being modified" maybe that causes it to behave as if it were a pipe or something :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default amount of memory used by `less` depends on whether it is reading a file or from a pipe; it's not clear what happens when reading redirected input from a file (`less < FilePath` instead of `less FilePath`).

The following excerpt from the manual page (on Ununtu 16.04) shows how to control the memory which `less` allocates:-

> -b**n** or --buffers=**n**
>   Specifies the amount of buffer space less will use for each file, in units of kilobytes (1024 bytes).  By default  64 K  of buffer space  is  used  for each file (unless the file is a pipe; see the **-B** option).  The **-b** option specifies instead that **n** kilobytes of buffer space should be used for each file.  If **n** is **-1**, buffer space is unlimited; that is, the entire file can be read  into memory.
>   -B or --auto-buffers
>   By  default,  when data is read from a pipe, buffers are allocated automatically as needed.  If a large amount of data is read from
>   the pipe, this can cause a large amount of memory to be allocated.  The **-B** option disables this automatic allocation of buffers for pipes,  so  that only 64 K (or the amount of space specified by the **-b** option) is used for the pipe.  Warning: use of **-B** can result in erroneous display, since only the most recently viewed part of the piped data is kept in memory; any earlier data is lost.

I read this as meaning that, when reading from a pipe, **-b** is not used unless **-B** is also an option. If you want this specified on every run, then add `export LESS='-B'` to your environment (in `bash` this would be a line in `~/.bashrc`).

Note that this will limit the memory `less` tries to allocate, whether memory is constrained by inadequate swap space or by the 4GB maximum program space on a 32-bit OS.